Error "Session cookie exceeds allowed 4096 bytes." in next-auth using Next.js 14 typescript
Previously I used next.js version 13.x.x then upgraded to next.js version 14.x.x When using next.js 13, authentication with next-auth runs smoothly, but after upgrading to next.js 14 an error like this occurs in the terminal console
message: 'Session cookie exceeds allowed 4096 bytes.'
this is my complete code in authoptions
import { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import prisma from "./prisma";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            credentials: {
                email: { label: 'email', type: 'text' },
                password: { label: 'password', type: 'password' },
            },

            authorize: async (credential) => {
                if (!credential?.email || !credential?.password) {
                    throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
                }

                const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                    where: { email: credential.email },
                    include: {
                        histories: true,
                        resto: true,
                    }
                });

                if (!user || !user?.password) {
                    throw new Error("Email does not match any user...");
                }

                const isCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(credential.password, user.password)
                if (!isCorrect) {
                    throw new Error("Password salah euy")
                }

                return {
                    ...user,
                    id: user.id.toString(),
                    name: user.name,
                    role: user.role,
                };
            },
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        jwt: async ({ token, user, session, trigger }) => {
            if (trigger === 'update') {
                return {
                    ...token,
                    ...session.user
                }
            }

            if (user) {
                const userRelation = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                    where: { id: Number(user.id) },
                    include: {
                        histories: true,
                        resto: true,
                    }
                });

                if (!userRelation) {
                    throw new Error("User not found");
                }

                return {
                    ...token,
                    // id: user.id,
                    ...userRelation
                };
            }

            if (token.name !== null && token.name !== undefined) {
                await prisma.user.update({
                    where: { id: Number(token.id) },
                    data: { name: token.name }
                });
            }

            return token;
        },
        session: async ({ session, token, user }) => {
            const newSession = {
                ...session,
                user: {
                    ...session.user,
                    id: token.id,
                    name: token.name,
                    role: token.role,
                }
            }

            return newSession;
        },
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/',
        error: '/',
    },
    debug: true,
    session: { strategy: "jwt" },
    secret: "rahasia",
}

then call the authoptions in file route.ts
// route.ts
import { authOptions } from '@/lib/auth';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }

and this is my file next-auth.d.ts
// next-auth.d.ts
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      id: string;
      name: string;
      email: string;
      role: string;
      [key: string]: string;
    };
  }
}

How may I solve the issue? or i should be downgrade to next.js version 13.x.x. again

actually it isn't an error, just warning. Because of your data cannot fit in single cookie. so that next-auth is spliting your whole data into browser's cookie max size. do not worry. Maybe some backend service which doesn't support the splitted cookies may trigger an error.

Thank you for your help, the solution I came up with was to summarize the code in the JWT callback to be like this
if (!user) return token return {    ...token,    id: user.id,    role: user.role, }
and it's work for me

I changed the body of the jwt callback to be more concise, and it worked
jwt: async ({ token, user, session, trigger }) => {
        if (trigger === 'update') {
            return {
                ...token,
                ...session.user
            }
        }

        if (user) {
            if (!user) return token

            return {
                ...token,
                id: user.id,
                role: user.role,
            }
        }

        if (token.name !== null && token.name !== undefined) {
            await prisma.user.update({
                where: { id: Number(token.id) },
                data: { name: token.name }
            });
        }

        return token;
    },

